# How to set a default value for attribute if it doesn't exist in the XDocument object

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to load an xml file.
I did this:

```
from e in XDocument.Load(stream).Root.Elements("cust")
                            select new Customer
                            {
                                MemeberID = (int)e.Attribute("custid"),
                                CustomerID = (int)e.Attribute("custid"),
                                FirstName = (string)e.Attribute("fname"),
                                LastName = (string)e.Attribute("lname"),
                                ShowsNumber = (int)e.Attribute("count_noshow"),
                                VisitNumber = (int)e.Attribute("count_resos"),
                                Cancellation = (int)e.Attribute("count_cancel"),
                                MobileNumber = (string)e.Element("phone").Attribute("phonenumber")
                            })
```

even thing was working good, but now i have a situation in which the xml document is not neccessary to have the `mobilenuber` attribute. 
so can I set a default value for this mobile number if it wasn't there in the xml node?

many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attribute not required:

```
MobileNumber = (string)e.Element("phone").Attribute("phonenumber") ?? defaultValue
```

Element not required:

```
MobileNumber = e.Element("phone") != null ? (string)e.Element("phone").Attribute("phonenumber") : defaultValue
```

Comment: that is not neceessary works, becaues the "phone" element maybe not be there, so I got the exception: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: You said it's not necessary to have the attribute. Now it's not necessary to have the element? Edit: Fixed for optional XML element